# Directory slash redirects? Does this still happen?

Tags: performance, redirect

I was reading an article [referenced by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html) about [Yahoo's "Best Practices" for speeding up a website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn), and I noticed this little gem:

> One of the most wasteful redirects
>   happens frequently and web developers
>   are generally not aware of it. It
>   occurs when a trailing slash (/) is
>   missing from a URL that should
>   otherwise have one. For example, going
>   to
>   http://astrology.yahoo.com/astrology
>   results in a 301 response containing a
>   redirect to
>   http://astrology.yahoo.com/astrology/
>   (notice the added trailing slash).
>   This is fixed in Apache by using Alias
>   or mod_rewrite, or the DirectorySlash
>   directive if you're using Apache
>   handlers.

Does this still happen? The article is pretty old, as the web goes. I think I've been doing this for years. I don't think I've noticed this happening lately, but then again I've never really looked. Is this an Apache thing? Does IIS 7 do this?

I'm scared.  Hold me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it!

Here are some truncated requests run from the terminal.

```
curl -I  http://astrology.yahoo.com/astrology

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 13:24:24 GMT
Location: http://shine.yahoo.com/astrology/


curl -I http://wordpress.org/extend

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 13:26:17 GMT
Location: http://wordpress.org/extend/
```

Though it seems that IIS does it the other way:

```
curl -I http://www.iis.net/overview

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0

curl -I http://www.iis.net/overview/

HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.iis.net/overview
```

Guess it depends how you have it configured, but it's definitely something to optimise.

Comment: Well, I just tested it on my own site for both "mysite.com/Home/Index" and "mysite.com/Home/Index/" and both come back 200 OK.

Comment: So yeah, more fiddling shows that MVC3 sites don't do this. I'm not sure if that's because of something in IIS7 or something to do with routing in MVC. Your answer lead me down the right path, hopefully people that find this see my input in the comments.  Answer accepted. +1

Comment: If that's the case, it might be worth setting a rel=canonical link on the one you pick to ensure Google doesn't think they are duplicate content. Though to be honest, that would surprise me if they did.